# Is it possible to filter Django objects by custom python metric function?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get Query that contains similar object based on my custom defined function

```
def sessRatio(s1, s2):
    ratio = L.seqratio([s1.browser_family, s1.device, s1.os_family, s1.os_version, s1.ip, s1.browser_version],
                      [s2.browser_family, s2.device, s2.os_family, s2.os_version, s2.ip, s2.browser_version])
    ratio += boolRatio(s1.mobile==s2.mobile, s1.tablet==s2.tablet, s1.touch==s2.touch, s1.pc==s2.pc, s1.bot==s2.bot)
    if(len(s1.meta)>0 and len(s2.meta)>0):
        ratio += L.ratio(s1.meta, s2.meta)
        ratio /= 3
    else:
        ratio /= 2
    return ratio
```

so in my view I create one s1 object and want to get theese s2 that sessRatio(s1,s2)>0.5. Django filter works only on raw SQL so probably I can't use my python function there.

Comment: Where do the ratio functions come from? Can you share them as we may be able to create annotations that match them

Comment: I've used this, https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein-wheels/, L is shortcut for Levenshtein.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: SQLite for now.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a one-go database Query maybe a simple list of your s2 objects might be sufficient? Something like

```
s2_objects = [s2 for s2 in S2.objects.all() if sessRatio(s1, s2) > 0.5]
```

Whether this is a solution depends on how many s2 objects we are talking about. 
I believe it is not possible to use python functions for querying the database directly.

However, Django does allow some complex queries as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions). But that would mean rebuilding your filter function